# "to do over" and " to do over again"

Tags: grammar

"to do over" means " to do something again from the beginning, especially because you did it badly the first time"

I have the impression that "to do over again" has the same meaning(so it can be as early as only being the second attempt) but according to my logic it should be at least the 3rd time since it's "to do over" and "again"

Comment: It is the same meaning, you're right. But people say it anyway.

Comment: Yes', it's [Deja vu all over again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deja_Vu_All_Over_Again).

Comment: As Fagin reflected in *Reviewing the Situation*: **I think I'd better think it out again**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"to do over" and "to do over again" mean the same thing. It doesn't mean a "3rd time", which you mentioned. An explanation could be that there's something pleasing about embedding repetition in an expression about repetition.